# Codeigniter :Parsing array in view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, mysqli

I have 2 array indexes in my  `data array` `users` and `books` 
this is how i am creating this array in my controller

```
  public function getuserhistory($id){
            $query= $this->db->get_where('book_assign', array(
                'user_id'       =>  $id, 
            ));
            return $query->result();
        }
        public function booksrecord($id){
            $books= $this->db->get_where('books',array('id' =>  $id));
            return  $books->result();
        }
public function history($id){
        $results['user']= $this->usermodel->getuserhistory($id);
        foreach ($results as   $value) {
            foreach  ($value as   $subvalue) {
                $results[]['books']= $this->usermodel->booksrecord($subvalue->id);
            }
        }
        $data['data'] = $results;
 $this->load->view('history', $data);
}
```

following is the array that i get

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [book_id] => 1
                    [date_issue] => 2016-07-24 00:00:00
                    [date_return] => 2016-07-25 00:00:00
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [book_id] => 2
                    [date_issue] => 2016-07-24 00:00:00
                    [date_return] => 2016-07-25 00:00:00
                )

        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [books] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [title] => PHP Made Easy 
                            [author] => Dietel & Dietel 
                            [serial_no] => 232323
                            [qty] => 9
                            [row_no] => 1
                            [col_no] => 2
                            [status] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [description] => This is a book about php 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [books] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [title] => C++
                            [author] => Dietel & Dietel 
                            [serial_no] => 232323
                            [qty] => 9
                            [row_no] => 1
                            [col_no] => 2
                            [status] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [description] => This is a book about c++
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This array has one specific user in user index and  books assigned to that user in book index, I've to parse this array in a way that  can generate one row in a table where i can show each book assigned to a user in a separrate row . Please helpe me to parse this array 
this is the format i've to print

```
<tr>
    <th>User id </th>
    <th>Book Title </th>
    <th>Date Issued</th>
    <th> Date Return</th>
    <th> Action</th>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent level array is inconsistent with it's elements since first element is an interloper - only that one is user data while other elements are each book data. We can assume that sometimes there could be much more books returned. To keep consistency in that manner I would separate those arrays in two arrays which first holds user data and second one holds books array.

```
$user = array_shift($parent);
$books = $parent;// convinient naming for later use
```

Now, you can loop users and dedicate appropriate book using book id

```
if (count($user))
{
    foreach($user as $obj)
    {
        $rows = "<tr><td>$obj->user->id</td>";
        foreach($books as $book)
        {
            if($book->id == $obj->book_id)
            {
                $rows .= "<td>$book->title</td>";
            }
            break;
        }
        $rows .= "<td>$obj->date_issued</td>";
        $rows .= "<td>$obj->date_returned</td>";
        $rows .= "<td>Action</td></tr>";
    }
    echo $rows;
}
```

Check this if works.
Although this (sh|c)ould work, see to return less data from DB and always try to use DRY methodology. Here you have many objects returned (user key from your array) just for different book id needed. It is pretty much expensive approach and you can check how to use concat in DB for book id or similar function.